# Google Maps API V3 and Javascript Results and Markers

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-maps, google-maps-markers

EDIT: Basically like the ASDA Store Locator

I have a store locator where when you type in your postcode and it shows the 3 stores that are close to you. From this 3 markers appear on the map for each location. The data is pulled in from a MYSQL database and that is where the lat and long is stored. What i am after is have the results numbered say 1,2 and 3 and a different marker with the numbers 1 2 and 3 on so they know what result store relates to what marker. I know how to create markers but i am im unsure how to apply this. Here is my code that i have used to show the results and display the markers on the map:

PHP

```
<?php which displays the results down the side of the map..
        if(isset($stores)){
            foreach($stores as $store){ ?>

            <div class="stores">
            <p class="name"><?php echo $store['name']; ?></p>
            <p class="address"><?php echo $store['address']; ?></p>
            <p class="address"><?php echo $store['postcode']; ?></p> 
            </div>

            <php number_format($store['distance'],2) ?> miles   

       <?php
          }
        }
        ?>
```

To get the markers for each result on the map i obviously used javascript:

```
function initialize() {

    var locations = [];     
    <?php
    $count = 0;
    foreach($stores as $store){
        ?>
        locations.push(['<?php echo $store['name'] ?>','<?php echo $store['lat'] ?>','<?php echo $store['lng'] ?>','<?php echo $count++; ?>']);
        <?php           
    }
    ?>

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        zoom: 5,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(55.136319, -2.504183),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        map: map
      });
    }

    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function() {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
    })(marker, i));
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

This displays the default marker but if i was to declare each marker a image or colour, how do i apply it to the array results for each result? Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Markers have an [icon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#MarkerOptions) property where you can change the image that is used.  I would recommend having a marker icon for each location with the index in the name (e.g. marker0.png, marker1.png, marker2.png).  Then set the icon when you create the marker.

Google has different ones you can grab, but the urls are not as easy to find all the time.  Here is a site that lists some of them: http://jg.org/mapping/icons.html

```
  for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
        icon: "url/to/the/marker/marker" + i + ".png",
        map: map
      });
    }
```

Comment: Well this is just what i was looking for! Had a custom marker and god forbid all i needed to do was create that line using the icon method- thank you so much :D.

Answer (score 1):

I did this a while back with the following approach. When I declared my marker I used.

```
var marker = createMarker(map,point,label,html,rank,type);
```

Then

```
function createMarker(map, latlng, title, html, rank,type) {
   var image = new google.maps.MarkerImage("images/goldPin.png",
    // This marker is 24 pixels wide by 37 pixels tall.
    new google.maps.Size(24, 37),
    // The origin for this image is 0,0.
    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 0,37.
    new google.maps.Point(15, 20)); 

    var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('images/goldPinShadow.png',
    // The shadow image is larger in the horizontal dimension
    // while the position and offset are the same as for the main image.
    new google.maps.Size(31, 37),
    new google.maps.Point(0,0),
    new google.maps.Point(15, 20));
    // Shapes define the clickable region of the icon.
    // The type defines an HTML <area> element 'poly' which
    // traces out a polygon as a series of X,Y points. The final
    // coordinate closes the poly by connecting to the first
    // coordinate.  

    var shape = {
        coord: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18 , 1],
        type: 'poly'
    };

    switch (type) {
        case "general":
            var markerOptions = {
            title: title,
            shadow: shadow,
            icon: image,
            shape: shape,
            position: latlng,
            map: map
        }
        break;
        /*
        more types go here
        */      
}

var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markerOptions);

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
    var infowindowOptions = {
      content: html
    }
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(infowindowOptions);
        setInfowindow(infowindow);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseover", function() {

});
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "mouseout", function() {

});

    return marker;
}
```

Let me not forget to mention that I used custom markers with my application which I strongly encourage.

Comment: Hey, thanks for this. i looked at this example earlier today and seems really handy. Fortunately, the snippet above works easier for me as i already had the layout used and is easier to implement into my build. Thanks for your help and i will save this to use in the future!